# integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the solution?
 $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}}dx$$
I have already tried to solve this integration. But I failed.

Comment: What is it that you tried?

Answer (score 2):

For first, get rid of one parameter. The problem is clearly equivalent to finding:
$$ \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)\sin(x+2c)}}=\sqrt{2}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos(2c)-\cos(2x+2c)}} $$
or:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{K-\cos x}}=-\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{(K-y)(1-y^2)}} $$
that is an elliptic integral.